# Modify SQL Server stored procedure to check for condition before executing Update statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Azure SQL Server - I have an inherited stored procedure which runs asynchronously, triggered by an Azure Service Fabric service which runs infinitely:

```
PROCEDURE Sources.ForIndexing
    (@SourceId BIGINT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @BatchId uniqueidentifier

    SELECT @BatchId = CaptureBatch
    FROM [Data].[Raw]
    WHERE CaptureId = (SELECT MAX(CaptureId)
                       FROM [Data].[Raw]
                       WHERE SourceId = @SourceId)

    UPDATE [Data].[Raw]
    SET [Status] = 501
    WHERE SourceId = @SourceId
      AND CaptureBatch = @BatchId
END
GO
```

In this `Data.Raw` table `CaptureId` is the Primary Key and is auto-incrementing.  The records in this table are grouped by `SourceId` and  `CaptureBatch`. One `SourceId` can have several `CaptureBatch's`. The first part of this procedure finds the latest `CaptureBatch` group by looking at the `MAX` `CaptureId` of a given `SourceId`. The `UPDATE` statement then sets the `Status` column of those records to 501.

What I need to do is add a condition to the stored procedure where, after the SELECT statement runs, says if the `Status` column of any given record over which this procedure iterates has a value of 1, do **not** execute the `UPDATE` statement on that record.

I thought it might be as simple as modifying the SELECT part to say:

```
WHERE CaptureId = (SELECT MAX(CaptureId)
                   FROM [Data].[Raw]
                   WHERE SourceId = @SourceId
                     AND Status <> 1)
```

But I believe that's only going to select a `Status` that's not 1 for that **one** record which contains the `MAX` `CaptureId`, correct? I may be overthinking this, but it seems I need some kind of `IF` statement added to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP (1)
   @BatchId = r.CaptureBatch
FROM [Data].[Raw] r
WHERE r.SourceId = @SourceId
ORDER BY r.CaptureId DESC

UPDATE r SET 
   [Status] = 501
FROM [Data].[Raw] r
WHERE r.SourceId = @SourceId
  AND r.CaptureBatch = @BatchId
  AND r.Status <> 1
```

Comment: CaptureID is the unique primary key.  Many records can have the same CaptureBatch, however.  So for example, SourceId 1 may have 200 records: 100 records with CaptureBatch ABC and 100 records with CaptureBatch XYZ.  Say that CaptureBatch XYZ was the latest inserted CaptureBatch: we only want to affect CaptureBatch XYZ. To determine which CaptureBatch should be affected, we look at MAX CaptureID of that CaptureBatch because we always want to affect the latest CaptureBatch with UPDATE statement.

Comment: Like this? Very straightforward to understand required logic.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, this looks like an interesting approach. So is your code intended to replace the entire stored procedure then?  Or get inserted after a certain part of the existing?

Comment: Yes, this is supposed to replace the original code (except variable declaration).

Comment: Ok - I will try it.  I think this will work.  I will mark this as the answer as soon as I confirm.  Thanks.

Comment: Ivan - I want to make sure we are on the same page. I do NOT want to run the UPDATE statement on any record that has status = 1.  Is your code correct for this?  The part that says "AND r.status =1" makes me uncertain.  Should it be "AND r.status <> 1?"  Or is your code correct because the statement says If NOT exists?  I'm a little unfamiliar with if not exists, so just want to make sure.

Comment: If there are two rows per `@SourceId and @BatchId` with `status = 1` and `status = 2` should the second row be updated? Or nothing must be updated because this batch contains row with `status=1`?

Comment: Good question to ask - yes the second row, or any row with a status other than 1, should be updated.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF (SELECT count(CaptureId)
                       FROM [Data].[Raw]
                       WHERE SourceId = @SourceId and Status = 1) > 0 BEGIN
 UPDATE [Data].[Raw]
    SET [Status] = 501
    WHERE SourceId = @SourceId
      AND CaptureBatch = @BatchId
END
```

Comment: I don't understand how that IF statement considers anything about the value of the `Status` field.

Comment: We do NOT want to update rows with a status that equals 1.